# Как парсить JSON массив на python

Tags: python, json

Подскажите как достать отсюда название игр и фору, пожалуйста)

[JSON](https://1xstavka.ru/LineFeed/Get1x2_VZip?sports=1&count=200&tf=2200000&tz=7&mode=4&subGames=175162887&country=1&partner=51&getEmpty=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В `python` есть замечательный модуль `json` вам необходимо ознакомиться с его документацией.

Берёте открываете json-файл, загружаете его библиотекой, если он "валидный" получите словарь, далее боритесь со словарём - как из него извлечь нужные данные:

```
import json
with open(my_file.json) as f:
    my_dict = json.load(f)

print my_dict["Error"]
```

Если у вас уже текстовый json используйте `json.loads`.

Comment: Подскажи, пожалуйста, почему это не работает?
rs = requests.get('https://1xstavka.ru/LineFeed/Get1x2_VZip?sports=1&count=200&tf=2200000&tz=7&mode=4&subGames=175162887&country=1&partner=51&getEmpty=true')

data = rs.json()

store = data["Value"][0]["O1"]["O2"]

Comment: Потому что "O1" и "O2" - два разных ключа. Значение каждого нужно получать отдельно: `data["Value"][0]["O1"]` и `data["Value"][0]["O2"]`

Comment: Ок, еще вопрос, мне нужно достать значение "P", который находится в массиве "E", который находится в массиве "Value", как это можно сделать?)

Comment: Для начала сделать `data['Value'][0]['E']` и взглянуть на результат. Это будет список словарей, но не каждый из них содержит ключ "P". Нужно обойти этот список и из каждого словаря попытаться вытащить значение "P".
А так как "Values" это также список словарей, то дальше нужно будет тянуть `data['Value'][1]['E']` и так далее. То есть это тоже нужно делать в цикле.